# Temporarily cannot delete files via FTP (550 Error on ISS7)

Tags: file-io, iis-7, ftp

Our website is constantly reading from a "discovery" folder within an FTP directory. It will try to delete files after x amount of time. It constantly gets a 550 error when trying to delete some of the files. Eventually, after the site (basically, ftp user) tries enough time, the file is "released" and the the user is able to delete the file.

I do not know if I can't delete these files temporarily because they are being uploaded, or if another process is accessing them.

Comment: This may be off-topic as it does not seem to be about programming.

Answer (score 0):

yes, May be some other process can be holded that or else that is readonly file. If it is readonly you need to remove that readonly attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your directadmin or whatever your admin access is.

Via directadmin (example : www.domain.com:2222) than select files on the right top.

Search the folder or file in the root and click on "Reset owner". 
After that you'll be able to delete the file via Filezilla.